# Increasing search radius for way points in Here Maps Fleet Telematics API

Tags: here-api, here-maps-rest

I am regularly getting the error 'Cannot match 52.19888/11.32296 onto a road link with 100.0m search radius'. In these cases, the location is often a warehouse that is indeed more than 100 meters from the nearest public road.

Here is an example query: http://fleet.api.here.com/2/calculateroute.json?mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&driver_cost=20&currency=EUR&rollups=total,country,tollsys,country;tollsys&commercial=1&shippedHazardousGoods=0&waypoint0=52.51,13.42&waypoint1=52.2787499,11.4330726&tollVehicleType=3&vehicle_cost=0.5&fuelType=Diesel&emissionType=6&length=1500cm&height=270cm&heightAbove1stAxle=120cm&vehicleWeight=7000kg&vehicleNumberAxles=2&trailerType=2&trailersCount=1&trailerNumberAxles=4&trailerHeight=270cm

Is there a way to increase the search radius for the way points in the Fleet Telematics API? I know that it is possible in the Route API, but can't find a way to do it for Fleet.

Or is there another way to get around this error message and get a valid route? For these calculations, I do not need the exact turn-by-turn directions: a route that is similar to the actual route a truck would drive would be enough.

Comment: Can you provide the sample query (without App ID and App Code) please?

Comment: Edited the question to include an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the `routeMatch` parameter with value `1` so that your waypoints will be treated as a GPS trace and the algorithm will return the most probable route along the trace.

Comment: That could be a workaround, but unfortunately it sometimes drops points with the error "Ignoring Trace Point X/Y, because it is far away from the neighbors"